Назначение устройства печати для AutoCAD (NanoCAD)
Код ниже позволяет для NanoCAD (*как AutoCAD) назначить для всех Листов (пространство листа) устройство печати "Встроенный PDF-принтер", сохранив имеющийся в настройках размер бумаги.
Подскажите пожалуйста как добавить в этот код аналогично назначение плоттера "Встроенный PDF-принтер" (сохранив имеющийся в настройках размер бумаги) НО ДЛЯ Пространства Модели?
namespace PrintDocument
{
    public partial class PlotDocument
    {
        [Teigha.Runtime.CommandMethod("PlotDocument")]
        public void PrintDocument()
        {
            // Получение ссылки на активный документ
            HostMgd.ApplicationServices.Document doc = HostMgd.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
            nanoCAD.Document comDoc = doc.AcadDocument as nanoCAD.Document;

            // Получение ссылки на редактор активного документа
            HostMgd.EditorInput.Editor ed = doc.Editor;

            // Получение ссылки на активный лист документа
            OdaX.AcadLayout activeLayout = comDoc.ActiveLayout;

            // Получение ссылки на свойство Plot активного документа
            nanoCAD.Plot plot = (nanoCAD.Plot)comDoc.Plot;

            try
            {
                // Назначение всем листам документа
                foreach (OdaX.IAcadLayout layout in comDoc.Layouts)
                {
                    // Получение ссылки на расширенные настройки печати
                    nanoCAD.InanoCADPlotCustomParams customPlotSettings = plot.CustomPlotSettings[layout];

                    string plotsize = layout.CanonicalMediaName;

                    // Вывод в консоль настроек до изменения
                    ed.WriteMessage("");
                    ed.WriteMessage("before: {0}:{1},{2},{3}", layout.Name, layout.ConfigName, layout.CanonicalMediaName, layout.PlotType);

                    // Назначение активному листу встроенного pdf-принтера
                    layout.ConfigName = "Встроенный PDF-принтер";

                    // Назначение активному листу имеющегося формата бумаги
                    layout.CanonicalMediaName = plotsize;

                    // Передаем измененные пользовательские настройки в лист
                    plot.CustomPlotSettings[layout] = customPlotSettings;

                    // Вывод в консоль настроек после изменения
                    ed.WriteMessage("after: {0}:{1},{2},{3}", layout.Name, layout.ConfigName, layout.CanonicalMediaName, layout.PlotType);
                    ed.WriteMessage("------------------------------------------------------------");
                }

                // Сообщение пользователю
                ed.WriteMessage("Все Листы были установлены для печати на 'Встроенный PDF-принтер'");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                // Сообщение пользователю
                ed.WriteMessage("Все Листы были установлены для печати на 'Встроенный PDF-принтер'");
            }

        }

    }
}

